# PayPal 403 Forbidden - Access to resource on the server is denied

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

My website has been working correctly for many years. However, today my paypal integration stopped working. Normally it shows the buy now button but now instead it is giving the following error:
403 Forbidden
Access to this resource on the server is denied!

```
// Custom Paypal Hash = IP|||||Shoppingcart|||||DBID|||||Language
            $custom = getRealIpAddr()."|||||".$_SESSION['cart']."|||||".makeSafe($_GET['i'])."|||||".$lang;
            $pphash = create_paypal_hash(makeSafe($_SESSION['cart']), '', create_password('########'), $custom);
            $tosend = base64_encode(urlencode($pphash));
            $cgi = "http://www.********.com/pl/b.pl?a=".$tosend; // TEST LINE
            echo file_get_contents($cgi);
```

If i navigate to the URL manually http://********.com/pl/b.pl?a=fsdfdsfsd it shows the buy button as normal.

Permission for the b.pl file is 0755